# when will the payment complete using the paypal python sdk?

Tags: python, paypal, sdk

i followed some of the code listed in https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK to build the payment. Question is at which stage the payment is completed? My understanding is that it is completed after "Authorize Payment" and before redirect user to "return_url", cause I think the "return_url" should do something like "tell user has completed the payment" not doing the payment. I am not sure if my thought right. Below is the payment flow.

Create Payment in python app

```
... skipped
"return_url": "xxx.com/payment/execute",
...
```

Authorize Payment in python app

```
...
Redirect user to approval_url (paypal page)
...
```

After user fill all the info in the paypal, it redirect user to return_url, which is below.

Execute Payment in xxx.com/payment/execute

```
...
curl 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/'+paymentId+'/execute';
...
```

after that I get JSON

```
    {
  "id": "PAYID-LT3I25Y9M527750ER784091X",
  "intent": "sale",
  "state": "approved",
  "cart": "1L498981HN342484R",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal",
    "status": "UNVERIFIED",
    "payer_info": {
      "email": "ji@gmail.com",
      "first_name": "ukf",
      "last_name": "tfutf",
      "payer_id": "ZD7ELNRCHVLPY",
      "shipping_address": {
        "recipient_name": "ukf tfutf",
        "line1": "ktf",
        "city": "ktfu",
        "state": "",
        "postal_code": "",
        "country_code": "HK"
      },
      "country_code": "HK"
    }
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "5.00",
        "currency": "USD",
        "details": {}
      },
      "payee": {
        "merchant_id": "4J8HJBF56QT24",
        "email": "facilitator@gmail.com"
      },
      "description": "This is the payment transaction description.",
      "item_list": {
        "items": [
          {
            "name": "item",
            "sku": "item",
            "price": "5.00",
            "currency": "USD",
            "quantity": 1
          }
        ],
        "shipping_address": {
          "recipient_name": "ukf tfutf",
          "line1": "ktf",
          "city": "ktfu",
          "state": "",
          "postal_code": "",
          "country_code": "HK"
        },
        "shipping_options": [
          null
        ]
      },
      "related_resources": [
        {
          "sale": {
            "id": "96712163V8788712D",
            "state": "completed",
            "amount": {
              "total": "5.00",
              "currency": "USD",
              "details": {
                "subtotal": "5.00"
              }
            },
            "payment_mode": "INSTANT_TRANSFER",
            "protection_eligibility": "ELIGIBLE",
            "protection_eligibility_type": "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE, UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE",
            "transaction_fee": {
              "value": "0.47",
              "currency": "USD"
            },
            "receipt_id": "2545046194101961",
            "parent_payment": "PAYID-LT3I25Y9M527750ER784091X",
            "create_time": "2019-06-04T15:29:48                  Z",
            "update_time": "2019-06-04T15:29:48                  Z",
            "links": [
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/96712163V8788712D",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/96712163V8788712D/refund",
                "rel": "refund",
                "method": "POST"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LT3I25Y9M527750ER784091X",
                "rel": "parent_payment",
                "method": "GET"
              }
            ],
            "soft_descriptor": "PAYPAL *TESTFACILIT"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "create_time": "2019-06-04T15:29:49   Z",
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LT3I25Y9M527750ER784091X",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The payment is completed on PayPal's side when the user approves the payment on the PayPal site. After that it redirects the user to the redirect_url. This web page should indeed inform the user that their payment is completed. It is likely that you can inspect this transaction/payment on the paypal sandbox so long as it did not error.

Also note that the SDK you are using is actually going deprecated soon. On the github you linked there it reads "Please note that if you are integrating with PayPal Checkout, this SDK and corresponding API v1/payments are in the process of being deprecated." I instead would recommend that you try to integrate with this SDK instead: https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Python-SDK which is PayPal's newest release. In addition to using the newer SDK I would recommend trying to use PayPal's Smart Checkout Buttons. They should make your life a little bit easier.

I have been using these SDK's in various projects for about the past two months and have not personally found it a straightforward process, but hopefully this helps!

Comment: thx for answer, if the payment is completed before redirect to "return_url", is that mean the return_url can be "localhost:80" in production? cause I type localhost, it work in sandbox too.

Comment: The return_url should not be localhost in production. Localhost is a webpage that runs locally (as in on your computer). If other people are redirected to localhost, their localhost will refer to the one running on their computer, not yours. They will not see the same webpage that you do. In addition to this, localhost is mostly meant to be used as a testing environment. Theoretically any valid URL can be used for the return_url. I recommend that this URL be the same page the user was on before being redirected to paypal, or make a landing page to tell the user their order was successful.

Comment: I am building the paypal for in-app payment, and I did not own a public domain, so can I start a server inside the app, so that it will redirect user to return_url?